# How do I read a binary file in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps

How can I read a binary file in a Windows Store app, or more specifically how can I create my Stream, when the System.IO namespace contains no File class?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454050.aspx) examples for BinaryReader unhelpfully use File!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You always access files in Windows Store apps using [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) class:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
```

You can then get the binary contents of the file using the WinRT APIs:

```
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
byte[] bytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

If you want to use [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) you need a stream instead:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("a");
Stream stream = (await file.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead();
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

Make sure you only use [ReadBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) for binary data in this case which doesn't take encoding into account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In case it is helpful, here is the using statement for IBuffer.ToArray(): using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;