# c# image to byte[] windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I found many solutions for this problem so far but none of them are working for me because I cant use the `File.ReadAllBytes` in WP8.1 or I've got problems setting the URISource of the BitmapImage.

I'am using the following code to pick a Image from the Windows Phone image gallery.
()

```
        private void PickPhotoButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        //filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
        filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
        view.Activated += viewActivated;
    }
    ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> myImageList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
    ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap> alt_myImageList = new ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap>();
    private async void viewActivated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
    {
        FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

        if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;

            view.Activated -= viewActivated;

            foreach (var item in args.Files)
            {
                // instead of item args.Files[0];
                StorageFile storageFile = item;
                var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                var wbImage = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
                wbImage.SetSource(stream);

                var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                //bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(item.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
                myImageList.Add(bitmapImage);
                alt_myImageList.Add(wbImage);

                //Img.Source = bitmapImage;
                ImageGrid.ItemsSource = myImageList;
                ParentControl.Height = 450;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code I've tried to store the BitmapImage as well the WritableBitmap. most threads I've read so far are suggesting to use the WritableBitmap for my problem but If I do so, they wont get displayed.

For ImageGrid I am using the following XAML:

```
                    <GridView Name="ImageGrid">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                <Image Width="50" Stretch="Fill" Name="Img" Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

So as I said, after I picked one or more images I am only able to see them if I store  `ImageGrid.ItemsSource = myImageList;`. No succeess with `ImageGrid.ItemsSource = alt_myImageList;`

But my real problem is accessing and handling the image file in the following code:

```
private async void SendButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)                                {

if (myImageList != null && alt_myImageList != null && myImageList.Count == alt_myImageList.Count)

foreach (var item in alt_myImageList){

}
```

This is what I've tried so far in Sendbutton_Tapped function without success so far:

```
                                    var test = item.UriSource;
                                var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                                        "filename", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                                var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(imageFile);

                                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(item);
                                RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
                                var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
                                byte[] bufferS = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
                                var test2 = await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(bufferS.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

                                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                                WriteableBitmap wb = item;
                                await wb.SetSourceAsync();
                                byte[] buffer = null;
                                wb.PixelBuffer.CopyTo(buffer);

                                wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myimage.PixelWidth, myimage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Do you have any idea how I can achieve my goal to convert this image (BitmapImage or WritableBitmal) to a byte[] though I am able to upload it.

Thank You

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853778/1136211) for how to read a binary file.

Comment: Thx for linking. Worked perfectly!